# How to create dynamic reports in PHP with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, report

I'm designed a web application in PHP which conects to a database in MySQL, this application will generate reports according to the fields that a user choose from diferents tables, there is a way to do this, preference by code. (and software tool is acceptable too)

Answer (score 0):

I work with Zend Framework. In controller I am creating a form. Form values sending to model. Model function returns inserted id or an error. In controller I am checking this result and echoing it. It works not only in Zend.

Comment: I am not sure to understand you, but you did an insert, but I will do only select, don't sure if with select will be functionaltoo

Comment: isn't zend framework better for very big and large projects? This looks a bit to simple to be using zend framework

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you need but if you want get form value use js. If you want use js use jquery ... you can get selected value with jquery by name or id ... just have a look on jquery

example:

> $("#input_id").val()

and use it to generate your report...
add onclick or onchange to show report dinamically

If you want make it after submit.. I think it is quiet easy...